# how to add julia kernel in sage notebook for windows?

Tags: julia, sage

how to add julia kernel in sage notebook for windows?I have sagemath installed on windows but I can't install the kernel to use julia.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.